# Nifi 1.11.4 Installation Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 2

Tags: load, transform, extract, etl, apache-nifi

Stuck at Nifi installation. Can someoone pls help.

thanks

```
/nifi.sh start

Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
NiFi home: /Users/shivam/Downloads/nifi-1.11.4

Bootstrap Config File: /Users/shivam/Downloads/nifi-1.11.4/conf/bootstrap.conf

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3756)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1902)
    at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.start(RunNiFi.java:1040)
    at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.main(RunNiFi.java:237)
```

Answer (score 0):

NiFi currently supports Java 8 and 11, and it looks like you are using OpenJDK 14.

Answer (score 0):

When I searched the Internet regarding this exception, I found some post in https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@nifi.apache.org/msg101620.html, this is because the nifi is checking for major version of Java, and mine was java 11 (without any specific version of 11). So when it checks for major version, it checks for some period operator (.) and the version does not contain that. So I just tried to install Java 11.0.16 from Oracle website and now the issue got resolved.